# upload progress in FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using commons-net FTPClient to upload some files.
How can I get progress of upload (number of bytes uploaded up now)?

Thanks

Comment: have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591688/ftp-way-to-programatically-determine-time-remaining-or-bytes-transfered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use [CopyStreamListener](https://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/io/CopyStreamListener.html). Below you will find an example (copied from commons-io wiki) of file retrieval, so You can easily change it other-way-round.

```
    try {
            InputStream stO =
                new BufferedInputStream(
                    ftp.retrieveFileStream("foo.bar"),
                    ftp.getBufferSize());

            OutputStream stD =
                new FileOutputStream("bar.foo");

            org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(
                    stO,
                    stD,
                    ftp.getBufferSize(),
/* I'm using the UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE constant here, but you can use the size of file too */
                    org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamEvent.UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE,
                    new org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamAdapter() {
                        public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred,
                                int bytesTransferred,
                                long streamSize) {
                                // Your progress Control code here
                        }
            });
            ftp.completePendingCommand();
        } catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

Comment: i used this solution, method  public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred,int bytesTransferred,                     long streamSize)  called after every bytes transferred, i am not able to update my UI, as its flooded thread with UI update calls. I used in android anybody can help why it is happening @Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps it is better to us the CountingOutputStream since it seems intended for this very purpose ?

This is answered by someone here: [Monitoring progress using Apache Commons FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875837/monitoring-progress-using-apache-commons-ftpclient)